# How is it possible to make the heapsize large in codenameone apps?

Tags: codenameone

I want to make the heapsize large for apps with codenameone exactly like what we define  android:largeHeap="true" in manifest file how is it possible to define this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last, I do it with APKTool recompile, change and at the end build again.
There is good explanation for how to work with APKTool: [Use APKTool](http://www.miui-au.com/add-ons/apktool/)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't available on platforms other than Android so there is no Codename One specific adaptation of this. You can use a build argument to add this attribute for Android only but there will be nothing similar on other platforms to map this to.

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible adding android.LargeHeap to build Hint with value of true. i just want it for my android build not all of them.

Comment: We have android.xapplication_attr which you can set to android:largeHeap="true" and add other attributes too.

Comment: where have i to define this?

Comment: Its a build argument. Right click the project go to properties. In the codename one section select the build hints tab and paste the key/value appropriately. These are hints that are sent to the build servers to customize various things about the build process.